# BigCommerce API. How to create cart and how to search customers using wildcards

Tags: php, api, shopping-cart, bigcommerce

I'm working on BigCommerce API for client's website, I have following questions:

1. Is there any way to create cart or add products to cart? So far I have learned that we have to maintain shopping cart on our system and once everything is done we can create Order on BigCommerce using API and post all products which are in our own shopping cart, is this right or I'm wrong?
2. Is there any way to search/list customers or any other data using wildcards? I'm trying following but its not returning anything:

   ```
   $filters = array('store_credit' => '>100'); // to get customers have more than 100 credits
   ```

   // OR array('first_name' => '*ar*'); // to search for customers having "ar" in their first name

   ```
   $customers = Bigcommerce::getCustomers($filters);
   ```

Waiting for answers.

Answer (score 2):

There are no shopping cart APIs yet. So, the first part is hard to do via API.
Regarding search/filtering, wildcards can't be used. The search looks for 'ar' first name if you are specifying that as a filter.